# Can I make the out-of-camera jpegs from my Olympus camera less oversaturated?

Tags: olympus, saturation, olympus-omd

I am using an Olympus OM-D E-M1 II and I find that the jpegs it produces are oversaturated. I tried using the "natural" and "muted" picture settings (see below) and it did not have much effect, still oversaturated.

[image]

Anything I can do here to get more natural saturation levels, or am I stuck with post processing?

Answer (score 1):

All of this is of course a matter of taste; I also usually find the built-in tone curves (or "Picture Settings" or whatever) to be a bit over-saturated. Fortunately, Olympus offers quite a bit of control over this; in addition to starting with "Natural" or "Muted", you can *also* reduce the Saturation setting (page 63 in the manual). This setting is stored separately per mode, so you can make Muted *even more muted* while leaving Natural alone, if you like.

You may also want to play with Contrast and Highlight & Shadow to find settings more to your liking.